# JQuery String is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have the below piece of code and I would like to know why I am getting "String is not a function" error when trying to set the text or value of the component.

Thanks,

```
this._on(this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
        var city = ui.item.option.value;
        var array = city.split(',');
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        ui.item.option.text('aaa');
        ui.item.option.value('aaa');
        this._trigger("select", event, {

            item: ui.item.option

        });
    },

    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
```

Comment: try remove quotes from `"_removeIfInvalid"`

Comment: that sounds right ^ . the value of the `autocompletechange` key should be a function, like your `autocompleteselect` already is. as your error message says, it's trying to execute a string as a function.

Comment: `ui.item.option.text` and `ui.item.option.value` are also a strings and not functions.

Comment: Tried but no luck. Even if I remove autocompletechange completely it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `autocompletechange` expects function. But you are passing String **"_removeIfInvalid"**.

As @charlieetfl commented, Try removing quotes and  set as `autocompletechange: _removeIfInvalid`

Comment: Tried but no luck. Even if I remove autocompletechange completely it gives me same error.